# Join table with attributes yaml mapping - Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list_tb (
    list_id               VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY, 
    country               VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_tb (           
    id_str          VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,             
    name            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    statuses_count  INT(10)      NOT NULL   
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list_user_tb (
    list_id         VARCHAR(255),
    user_id         VARCHAR(255),
    priority        INT(10)  NOT NULL,
    date_added      DATETIME NOT NULL,
    date_removed    DATETIME NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (list_id, user_id)
);

ALTER TABLE list_user_tb 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_list_user_tb_list_tb FOREIGN KEY (list_id) REFERENCES list_tb(list_id);

ALTER TABLE list_user_tb 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_list_user_tb_users_tb FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users_tb(id_str);
```

I have list that can contain N users and user that can belong to M list. Join table has it's own attributes like dateAdded, dateRemoved etc. I will have operations like createList(list), createUser(user), list.addUserToList(user), list.removeUserFromList(user). On delete user I want him deleted form list_user_tb also. On deleteList I want removed all users belonging just to that list. It's clear that list_tb and Users_tb have one to many relations to list_user_tb,

I'm unsure if list_user_tb should have many to one relations back to user and list? It's just question weather I must adding and removing handle in php or mysql will handle that for me.

My question is about what is right mapping in Doctrine yaml for this? When I use doctrine `orm:convert-mapping yaml ./config/yaml --from-database --force` it creates just join manyToMany relation, but as I said I want join table with additional attributes. So I removed one foreign key and created mappings then added it manually to yaml.

I've also read these two articles

http://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/doctrine-2-how-to-handle-join-tables-with-extra-columns/

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Here is what I have so far.

//UsersTb

```
UsersTb:
    type: entity
    table: users_tb
    id:
        idStr:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
            fixed: false
            default: ''
            id: true
            column: id_str
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
            fixed: false
        statusesCount:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: false
            column: statuses_count
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

//ListTb.yml

```
ListTb:
    type: entity
    table: list_tb
    id:
        listId:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
            fixed: false
            default: ''
            id: true
            column: list_id
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        country:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
            fixed: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

//ListUserTb.yml

```
ListUserTb:
    type: entity
    table: list_user_tb
    indexes:
        IDX_6D2EC7B13DAE168B:
            columns:
                - list_id
    id:
        userId:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
            fixed: false
            id: true
            column: user_id
    id:
        idStr:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
            fixed: false
            id: true
            column: id_str
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        priority:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: false
        dateAdded:
            type: datetime
            nullable: false
            column: date_added
        dateRemoved:
            type: datetime
            nullable: false
            column: date_removed
    manyToOne:
        list:
            targetEntity: ListTb
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                list_id:
                    referencedColumnName: list_id
            orphanRemoval: false
        user:
            targetEntity: UsersTb
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                id_str:
                    referencedColumnName: id_str
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: As I see now there is additional complexity, since list_id and user_id are composite primary and foreign keys at same time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer, nicely explained on this link http://codemonkeys.be/2013/02/example-of-a-doctrine-2-x-many-to-many-association-class/#respond